# WI-FI problem in ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I've been struggling with the WI-FI support of my system for last few days! I've upgraded my ubuntu ver. from 18.04 lts to 18.10. After doing this, my WI-FI was okay for 5-6 days but after that it started disconnecting automatically after every 4-5 mins even when the signal seems to be appear, then I have to restart the network manager again and again periodically after 4-5 mins! Your help will really help me a lot. Here I've posted few more details, Have a look :

**OUTPUT OF `sudo lshw -C network` command:**

```
*-network                 
description: Wireless interface
product: QCA9377 802.11ac  Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: wlp1s0
version: 31
serial: f8:28:19:db:29:e7
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.18.0-17-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 ip=192.168.31.222 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:36 memory:e8800000-e89fffff
```

**Details Of laptop:**

```
Name : Lenovo idapad 320.
WIFI driver : ath10k_pci
```

Although I've a little doubt about physical ID which is set to 0. So have a look at the output of `sudo lshw -C network`!

Please help me as soon as possible as I've so many imp. pending works on my system. So, your help would be great to me !

**OUTPUT OF `nmcli device` command:**

```
DEVICE        TYPE            STATE            CONNECTION     
wlp1s0        wifi            connected        Unable to Connect 
enp2s0        ethernet        unavailable      --           
lo            loopback        unmanaged        --
```

**OUTPUT OF `ip addr show` command:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 54:e1:ad:64:79:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether f8:28:19:db:29:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.31.222/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
   valid_lft 41615sec preferred_lft 41615sec
inet6 fe80::b0c8:7396:bee9:cbbd/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**OUTPUT OF `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` command:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May 12  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

**OUTPUT OF `systemd-resolve --status wlp1s0` command:**

```
Link 3 (wlp1s0)
Current Scopes: DNS
LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
DNSOverTLS setting: no
DNSSEC setting: no
DNSSEC supported: no
Current DNS Server: 192.168.31.1
DNS Servers: 192.168.31.1
DNS Domain: ~.
```

**OUTPUT OF `cat /etc/resolv.conf` command:**

```
This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 192.168.31.1
```

**OUTPUT OF `sudo lshw -c network | grep 'configuration'` command:**

```
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.18.0-17-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 ip=192.168.31.222 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11 
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

**OUTPUT OF `mokutil --sb-state` command**

```
SecureBoot disabled
```

**OUTPUT OF `rfkill` command**

`ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0                blocked unblocked
 1 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth   blocked unblocked
 3 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92051/discussion-on-question-by-parth-pandya-wi-fi-problem-in-ubuntu-18-10).

Comment: What is the status of Wi-Fi stability issue now, @Parth Pandya? Did the solution suggested work?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, can you help me as well?

Comment: Do you see any kernel driver error messages when the wifi shutdown? You can check this with `dmesg` or `journalctl -k`, and append the relevant error messages to your post.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know which is the relevant error message I should be looking for. This is the result of `dmesg`:
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2kwx